# How to compare a word from a text file with another word?

Tags: python

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         for word in f:
             if word == 'President':
                print('a')
```

This doesn't print anything even though i have the word 'president' 4 times in the text file. How can I make it check

My text file looks like this:

```
President Kacey Genicke

President Alexandra Twomey

President Aldous Graddell

President Bernie Jenicek

Officer Cyrill Vernazza

Officer Sutton Spier

Officer Isabella Seer

Officer Abbey Holdforth

Faculty Officer Lennie Lomaz

Faculty Officer Brant Howle

Faculty Officer Dionysus Summerbell

Faculty Officer Calhoun Duguid

Faculty Officer Tremain Arnaez

Faculty Officer Mirabella Trathan

Faculty Officer Dex Darcy
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
   Kacey Genicke

   Alexandra Twomey

   Aldous Graddell

   Bernie Jenicek
```

I tried doing this:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
            if 'President' in line:
                print(line[10])
```

This gives me the first letter of each president.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop `for word in f:` does **not** iterate over *"words"* in a line, but does the same as `for line in f` - consuming lines of file **`f`**.

To check if `'President'` word is contained within a line, all you need is:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         if 'President' in line:
             print('a')
```

---

To print only lines that start with `President` word with prefix eliminated:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
     for line in f:
         if line.startswith('President'):
             print(line.replace('President', '').strip())
```

Comment: Thank you,
After I find the word 'president', is there some way I can put in a list the first name and last name of the person after the word but without the word 'president' in front?
Instead of printing, I tried appending, but it puts it with the word 'president' as well.

Comment: @Chiby, add expected output to your question

Comment: I want my output to look like this (they are all on a separate line but the comment makes it look weird):

Kacey Genicke


Alexandra Twomey


Aldous Graddell


Bernie Jenicek

I tried doing this:

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
            if 'President' in line:
                print(line[10])

This gives me only the first letter of each name, I need to find a way to give it a kind of "range" function I think.

Comment: @Chiby, output in comments is unreadable, post the formatted output into your question

Comment: @Chiby, see my update

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think it is your indenting. You can try the following:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    count = 0 
    for line in f:
        columns = line.split() 
        if len(columns) > 1 and 'President' in line:  
            print(columns[1], columns[2])
            count += 1
    print("There are ", count, "Presidents found")
```

This should print the whole line if `President` found in that particular line. We then will split the line in columns and print the columns accordingly

However, for such cases, using `awk` might be much more appropriate than python.

```
awk '/President/{c++; print $2,$3 } END { printf("There were %d Presidents found\n", c)}' file.txt
```

- Search for President
- Increment the counter c.
- Print second and third column
- END. Print the total occurences found.

Comment: I want it to print without the word 'President' in front of the names.

Comment: Ok that's not that hard. See Update